# Get the ID from POST response url

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to get the id from this url address which is the result of my api POST request on the other website, but so far i had no luck.
I need to extract this id=628044 in order to append it later in database for each order.

```
https://website.com/SI/VA/WebUI/Narocilo/NarociloView.aspx?nar_id=628044&pgat=pgatv
```

This is the POST cURL request from my php function:

```
$api_endpoint = 'https://website.com/SI/API/api/orgs/1111/orders';
$product_string = json_encode($generated, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
           
           $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $product_string);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
           $response = curl_exec($ch);
         
           $response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
           curl_close($ch);
```

I have tried getinfo(), CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL and i get nothing.

if i add $info = getinfo($ch);

i get this as a response:

```
    [url] => https://webiste.com/SI/API/api/orgs/1111/orders
    [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 201
    [header_size] => 335
    [request_size] => 685
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.253328
    [namelookup_time] => 0.001961
    [connect_time] => 0.008546
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.047713
    [size_upload] => 1628
    [size_download] => 2
    [speed_download] => 7
    [speed_upload] => 6434
    [download_content_length] => 2
    [upload_content_length] => 1628
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.047777
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 91.185.200.165
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.150
    [local_port] => 56108
    [http_version] => 3
    [protocol] => 2
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => HTTPS
    [appconnect_time_us] => 46918
    [connect_time_us] => 8546
    [namelookup_time_us] => 1961
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 47713
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 47777
    [total_time_us] => 253328
```

And there is no redirect_url!

Comment: You say this URL is part of the result. As in, it's one of the values in `$response`?

Comment: No, it is not. That's the result url from the website that i have write my order on. In response i get this : https://website.com/SI/API/api/orgs/1111/orders

Comment: What is your actual question here then? How to get this URL? Well we don’t know, you told us virtually nothing about the API you are using there. Or do you have this URL already, and the question is now simply how to extract that one parameter value from it? Then go check out `parse_url` and `parse_str`.

Comment: I don't understand where you expect this URL to come from. What result did you get when using `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`?

Comment: I want to extract this id from that URL, yes @CBroe. I have a foreach loop that reads orders one by one and writes them in the certain website. Every order that has been written with this POST request has it's own ID, obviously, like the one i already wrote in the beginning. I want for every order to get back (extract) only the ID from that URL.

Comment: Then use the functions I mentioned.

Comment: @El_Vanja i got this one: website.com/SI/API/api/orgs/1111/orders

Comment: So then you are saying, that you _don’t_ have this value yet, `https://website.com/SI/VA/WebUI/Narocilo/NarociloView.aspx?nar_id=628044&pgat=pgatv`? (That was what we are trying to determine here.)

Comment: @CBroe i would but i can't because i don't know how to return that URL that gives the ID. Yes that is correct.

Comment: Well we don’t know either! We have no idea what kind of API you are communicating with there. All the info you have given us so far, is _“which is the result of my api POST request”_ - how are we supposed to know, what that even _means_? You need to properly explain, what you are “getting back”, and how exactly.

Comment: I'm using partners API (restricted access) - RESTful protocol. If write ` $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); ` i get as a result : ` https://website.com/SI/API/api/orgs/175250/orders  `. I am new in cURL, i read that after i add this statement, that i would get the redirected url used in the last transaction, and this is not the expected result that i want.

Comment: Well, are you absolutely certain that your desired URL will be the last?